# DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL get guid C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I have this C# code:

```
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
        const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
        const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;

        if(msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        {
            if(wParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
            {
                // get GUID of inserted device
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

and on line commennted as "// get GUID of inserted device" I need to get current device GUID. How can I do it?

Comment: Lots of existing code out there, find it by googling "c# DEV_BROADCAST_HDR"

Comment: Thank you for this, but I trying to get info from DEV_BROADCAST_HDR structore and corresponding device_type DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE do not arrived at all when I plug in usb device, I ned it becase dbch_eventguid lays in DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE.

Comment: That's entirely normal, you'd get a DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE for a USB device.  If you're happy with the dbcc_classguid then you CreateFile() from the passed dbcc_name.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do and where you get stuck. Show how you are calling `RegisterDeviceNotification`. Maybe you want the USB drive letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be It's not a better solution, but I did like this

```
if (wParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
{
    DEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));
    if (pHdr.dbch_DeviceType == 2)
    {
        DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));
        char letter = UnitName(vol.dbcv_unitmask);
        // here we get drive mount point from bitmask
        string name = DriveLetter(letter);
        int bufferCapacity = 256;
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(bufferCapacity);
        // using drive mount point we can get structure that describes this drive
        GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(name,res,(uint) bufferCapacity);
        Guid g = Guid.Parse(res.ToString().Substring(11,36));
        Reducer.RememberCurrentDrive(g,letter);
    }
}
```

That was all what I need. Thanks for your help.